# No VGA output (even grub2) after successful install

Tags: 16.04, video, vga

I installed Ubuntu Server 16.04 on Dell PowerEdge 610 without errors.  Booting into the new system all BIOS messages show up on the screen, then VGA output goes black but monitor doesn't appear to lose signal.  Not even GRUB menu shows up.

The system actually boots all the way and I can ping it.  But can't do anything else (no ssh server installed at the moment).

The system is set to BIOS mode not UEFI.

Anyone have any ideas what's going on?  The installation UI had no problems driving the monitor.

Comment: pressing win key + F2 give me the login screen.. Before i press that i have no screen but monitor is awake

Answer (score 2):

First, try Ctl+Alt+F1, it should open a command line interface. (If that doesn't work try F2 or F3 instead of F1)

Then try running `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

After that, run `sudo reboot`, and hopefully it will be working. If not, go back into the command line and install VNC: `sudo apt-get install tightvnc`

To start the server, run `vncserver`

After VNC is setup, connect to the computer remotely with the program of your choice, then navigate to settings, and 'Additional Drivers'. Install any proprietary drivers available.

Reboot and cross your fingers!

If none of this works, but you can get to the command line, maybe try installing a different display manger.

If you are unable to get to the command line on the computer, as a last resort try removing the hard disk, attaching it to another linux system, and using chroot run the same commands.

Comment: I installed ubuntu server with no X11 (or desktop environment).  As mentioned the video display is gone before GRUB menu.  I don't see the GRUB menu to select boot options.  Because of this I don't think this is driver related - initramfs or kernel modules aren't even loaded at that point.